# Jade using Javascript variables

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug

I have the following example code

```
extends layout

block append content
 - var user = {name:'hello word'}
 include includes/header
 div.container
  p
   #{user.name}
  #blogs
    - each blog in blogs
      div.blog
         strong
          div.title
             a(href="/blog/"+blog._id)!= blog.title
         small
          div.created_at= blog.created_at
         div.body= blog.body.substring(0,100) + ' ... '
           a(href="/blog/"+blog._id)!= 'Read More'
  include includes/footer
```

This renders HTML output that contains

```
<p>
  <hello world><hello>
</p>
```

Can anyone explain what is going on here according to the [Jade tutorial](http://jade-lang.com/tutorial/#Javascript) this should render correctly ...

Comment: Depends on what you were expecting the output to be. What would you consider "*correct*" in this case?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you were expecting `hello world` as text:

```
<p>
    hello world
</p>
```

Then, Jade needs just a bit more instruction since the default meaning of a line-break and indent is a child element.

Options include:

- Keeping the element and text on the same line ("[*Inline in a Tag*](http://jade-lang.com/reference/)"):

  ```
  p #{user.name}
  ```

  Also, if that's the only text within the `<p>`:

  ```
  p= user.name
  ```
- Using a `|` to specify the line as text ("[*Piped Text*](http://jade-lang.com/reference/)"):

  ```
  p
    | #{user.name}
  ```
- Trailing the element with a `.` so all content under it is text ("[*Block in a Tag*](http://jade-lang.com/reference/)"):

  ```
  p.
    #{user.name}
  ```